# Does MinGW-w64 support C++14?

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

I have installed visual studio code, and I want to use it to build my C++ projects on Windows, so I need download MinGW-w64. But before doing that, I need know if the MinGW-w64 supports C++14?

Comment: Check what g++ compiler version comes with it. Usually it would support it.

Comment: If is recent distribution - yes, it does

Comment: If you are doing Windows development, I have to ask why you would not use the  Visual Studio IDE, which comes with a C++ compiler - the unfortunately named "Visual Studio Code" is basically a text editor.

Comment: "If is recent distribution - yes, it does", Mr. Severin Pappadeux, have you VERIFIED it by yourself? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply download it and try, it does not hurt your computer at all.

As said in MingGw-w64 website, "a pthreads library for C++11 threading support and simple integration with existing project."

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure it in the compiler of MinGW in Configuration => Compiler and in the section of "Toolchain Executables"